# How do I store Date objects in MongoDB that are cross compatible with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, go, time

I use both Node.js and Golang in my API stack. I need to store `Date` objects in MongoDB, but in Golang, I'm not sure how to create a `Date` object that's cross compatible between the two languages.

How do I make a `new Date()` in golang to store in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a driver to connect to mongo? Odds are it'll take care of the translation between a time.Time type in Go and a mongo Date type for you.

Edit: To be clear, try:

```
t := time.Now()
```

and save t directly into your mongo document